# What is the best way of setting limits of fuzz test input parameters in Foundry?

Tags: testing, foundry, fuzz-test

Let's take an example, where we have a stake function, with the stake's endTimestamp in uin64.

```
function stake(uint256 amount, uin64 endTimestamp)
```

It is assumed endTimestamp should never be less than the timestamp at which the stake function was called. What is the best way of creating such a limit in a Foundry test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundry implements function `bound(uint256 x, uint256 min, uint256 max)`, which bounds a variable parameter to a certain range. To bound an input parameter, you can do something like this:

```
function stake(uint256 amount, uin64 endTimestamp) {
        endtimestamp = uint64(bound(endTimestamp, block.timestamp, type(uint64).max))
        _;
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge-std/bound